# Anchor tag opens multiple pop-ups

Tags: jquery, html, modalpopup

I am creating a pop up that will display a pop up notifying the user they are leaving the website if the anchor tag they have selected is not a internal link.

I was able to find an [example online](http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/jquery-modal-tutorial/) that provides a tutorial on how to create a jquery modal.

```
    //Create my Pop-Up
var modal = (function(){
    var 
    method = {},
    $overlay,
    $modal,
    $content,
    $close;

    // Center the modal in the viewport
    method.center = function () {
        var top, left;

        top = Math.max($(window).height() - $modal.outerHeight(), 0) / 2;
        left = Math.max($(window).width() - $modal.outerWidth(), 0) / 2;

        $modal.css({
            top:top + $(window).scrollTop(), 
            left:left + $(window).scrollLeft()
        });
    };

    // Open the modal
    method.open = function (settings) {
        $content.empty().append(settings.content);

        $modal.css({
            width: settings.width || 'auto', 
            height: settings.height || 'auto'
        });

        method.center();
        $(window).bind('resize.modal', method.center);
        $modal.show();
        $overlay.show();
    };

    // Close the modal
    method.close = function () {
        $modal.hide();
        $overlay.hide();
        $content.empty();
        $(window).unbind('resize.modal');
    };

    // Generate the HTML and add it to the document
    $overlay = $('<div class="overlay" style="display: none;"></div>');
    $modal = $('<div class="modal" style="width: auto; height: auto; top: 369px; left: 782px; display: none;"></div>');
    $content = $('<div class="content2"></div>');
    $close = $('<a class="close" href="#">close</a>');

    $modal.hide();
    $overlay.hide();
    $modal.append($content, $close);

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('body').append($overlay, $modal);                     
    });

    $close.click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        method.close();
    });

    return method;
}());
```

With this example, the pop up is called when a link opens to a different site:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('a:not([href*="/mysiteurl"])').on('click',function(e){
        modal.open({content: "<p>You are now exiting the web site.  When you exit this site to access a different web site, you become subject to the other web site’s privacy policy and practices.  To learn about the other web site’s policy and practices, refer to the privacy policy statement posted on the web site’s home page</p>" + "<a href='#PrivacyPolicyLink'>Click Me</a>"});
        e.preventDefault();       
    });

});
```

When I click on a anchor tag that will send me to another site, the pop up will appear. The issue I am encountering is when I close the pop up, another pop up will appear right after. Based on some testing, it appears it will create a new pop up for every anchor tag that will cause the user to leave the website.

My question is: How can I have the pop up appear only for the anchor tag that is clicked on?

Comment: you could use an anonymous class, `.popup`, and delegate clicks that way. `$('a.popup').click(...`

Comment: @bowl0stu: The problem with that is I would need to go to every page and add that class if it contains an external link. I was hoping the approach I did would target any external link in the foreseeable future.

Comment: guess i've misunderstood what you're asking. your function looks sound. are you declaring, `$('a:not([href*="/mysiteurl"])').on('click',function(e){`, in multiple places? that could cause it to trigger multiple times

Comment: should you be matching `a[href*="/mysiteurl"]` in your `:not` clause?

Comment: @bowl0stu: For your question, no its only being called in my js file.Could it be that its in the document.ready?

Comment: @bowl0stu: I do not want it to match my site. I would only like the popup to appear when the link is not part of the site itself.

Comment: nah, `$(document).ready(` doesn't affect the state of the click handler in this case.
so like third party links? links available in iframes or something similar?

Comment: @bowl0stu: Yes third party links and no not in iframes. Although I do have another approach based on your popup class. Would it be a bad idea add the pop up class when pageloads to the page and then do what you did with the $('a.popup')

Comment: @bowl0stu: nevermind, it didnt work. It rendered the same results